# Move from one text field to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I make text field-1 move to another text field-2 by Swift when I write two numbers?

[image]

When I write 22, I want to automatically move to another text field-2.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = textField.text {

        let newStr = (text as NSString)
            .stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        if newStr.isEmpty {
            return true
        }
        let intvalue = Int(newStr)

        if textField.tag == 101 { print("101") // only 2 integer
             return (intvalue >= 0 && intvalue <= 99) ? true : false
        }
        else if textField.tag == 102 { print("102") // only 4 integer
             return (intvalue >= 0 && intvalue <= 9999) ? true : false
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: moving content of textfield or moving control to other textfield ?

Comment: moving control to other textfield

Comment: not related to your issue but `? true : false` is redundant

Comment: Simply you want to move from one textField to another textField on a certain condition?

Comment: yes when i write tow numbers like `23 or 35 or 19 `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create IBAction for both textfields like this and check first textfield's characters count in IBAction. If count is 2 second textfield will become active.

[image: Create IBAction]

```
@IBAction func textEntered(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if sender.tag == 101 && sender.text?.characters.count == 2
    {
      (self.view.subviews.first(where: { $0.tag == 102 }) as! UITextField).becomeFirstResponder()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)


func textDidChanged(textField: UITextField)
{
    if (textField.text) == "22"
    {
        newTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

add delegate to both the textfields
also add UITextFieldDelegate to your viewcontroller

Comment: @X.BOZO :- have added UITextFieldDelegate to your viewcontroller??.. and textfield.delegate = self, newTextField.delegate = self ??

Comment: yeah i add `textfield.delegate = self, newTextField.delegate = self ` and still not working ;/

Comment: i got error ` use of locl textdidchanged(textfiled):'before is declaration `

Comment: Ok see @Rajeshkumar R answer as he is showing the whole process in images perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a target for editingChanged event of your textField like below or simply drag an action from storyboard in to your class :

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

then in your selector do as follow :

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 101 && textField.text!.characters.count >= 2 {
        secondTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: i get error here `#selector(textFieldDidChange(_:))`

Comment: Even for the second text field the if condition would be true, change it to firstTextField instead of just textField.

Comment: i got this error ` use of unresolved identifier textfielddidchange `

Comment: Using tags for this is an anti-pattern. It's better to use IBOutlets for future proofness. If you change this tag on interface builder, you won't get any warnings/errors in the code.

Comment: You can also drag and drop the didChange action from that textfield in storyboard into your code, then it will give you a function to write code in it.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do more,
just modify your `shouldChangeCharactersIn range`

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let finalText = (textField.text ?? "")// + string

    if textField === self.textField1! && finalText.characters.count >= 2 {
        self.textField1.resignFirstResponder()
        self.textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    else if textField === self.textField2! && finalText.characters.count >= 4 {
        self.textField2.resignFirstResponder()
        self.textField1.becomeFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

    return true
   }
```

Try not to use the `tag` in the code as it's not understandable to other programmers after you on the project.